# ios6 device identification and profiling

Tags: iphone, ios6, profiling, uniqueidentifier, identification

I have made a social application, since I don't like apps that asks to create a profile...remember passwords...etc, my app works without login needed.

In order to identify an user, I use the UDID. In iOS6, Apple doesn't provide no more access to UDID, but forces developer to use the **identifierForVendor**, the problem is that this identifier changes if the application is deleted and installed again...or if the application is upgraded.

What are your suggestions to save users profiles?
Is there other ways to have a kind of "login" without an account?

Thank you very much.

Comment: There's a reason social apps require the user to create an account. One does not simply avoid it.

Comment: @H2CO3 [is right](http://cdn.memegenerator.net/instances/400x/33223609.jpg). Even when it was allowed, purely UDID-based auth had too many ways to break -- upgrading or otherwise replacing phones, for example. Stuff like `identifierForVendor` isn't a bad way to do a reauthentication shortcut, but don't depend on it entirely.

Comment: @rickster replacing phone is not a problem, I've introduced a way to export/import the profile from/to another device...the problem now is only when the user delete/reinstall the app. Other way to combine `identifierForVendor` with something else?